# matlab mvnrnd in gsl

Tags: c++, c, matlab, gsl

Hi i'm not sure if my algorithm is correct i'm trying to replicate the [mvnrnd](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/stats/mvnrnd.html) function of matlab but in gsl. I found an algorithm in some journal articles that produces a vector of multivariate normal, but i need a matrix of multivariate normal random numbers

lets say the distribution is Z~(mu,sigma);

assuming sigma is a matrix already positive definite.

**an algorithm i found off the web says to**

```
1. cholskey(sigma) = A
2. generate uniform gaussian vector r
3. matrix vector triangular product with gsl_blas_dtrmv A * r
4. add mu to Ar and that will be a vector of multivariate normal random numbers
```

**my method below**

**are the following changes belowcorrect to product a Matrix of random variables**

```
    1. cholskey(sigma) = A
    2. generate uniform gaussian matrix R
    3. matrix matrix scalar product AR
    4. add mu to AR and that will be a matrix of multivariate normal random numbers
```

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to do similar things here. May I know how did you generate the uniform gaussian vector in gsl. I saw there are box-muller methods mentioned. But would it matter if I just generate Gaussian random number one by one for a a vector? Will there be covariance due to pseudo random number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is correct. See e.g. [this Wikipedia entry on multivariate normal RNGs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution) which has this section:

> Drawing values from the distribution
>
> A widely used method for drawing a random vector x from the
>   N-dimensional multivariate normal distribution with mean vector μ and
>   covariance matrix Σ works as follows:
>
> 1. Find any real matrix A such that
>      A AT = Σ. When Σ is positive-definite, the Cholesky decomposition is
>      typically used. [...]
> 2. Let z = (z1, …, zN)T be a vector whose components are N
>      independent standard normal variates (which can be generated, for
>      example, by using the Box–Muller transform).
> 3. Let x be μ + Az. This has
>      the desired distribution due to the affine transformation property.

which describes the same algorithm.

There are also several implementations for [R](http://www.r-project.org), for example `mvrnorm` in the [MASS](http://cran.r-project.org/package=MASS) package which comes with every R installation.

Comment: thanks! didn't think I would get some one famous like yourself to answer my question